# Angular forms module disables a previously working form

Tags: angular, forms

This happens inside my angular 5 app:

I have this form, which works well:

```
<form name="pdfForm" method="post" [action]="pdfUrl" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" [value]="data">
  <button type="submit">
    Download as Pdf
  </button>
</form>
```

When I add the Forms Module to the application (which I need for another form) however, the above form stops working!

Does anyone know why? And what can I do about it?

Comment: What do you mean by "importing the Forms Module" ? Just import him in the related module ?

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working"? Does it generate an error? If so, what? Does it not display? Not submit?

Comment: It does nothing. No error. It seems that the submit event is not fired. With adding the Forms Module I mean adding the Forms Module to the imports in the App Module

Comment: When you import the forms module and you have a button inside a form this button is automatically assigned to be a submit button. Remove the type="submit" from your button and set the ngsubmit like: <form (ngSubmit)="mySubmitMethod()" ...>

Comment: See this plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/4fEaXJNn7CoLKysEqk1M. I don't have a submit function, the form should submit itself.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer myself. Angular seems to provide a ngNoForm directive | attribute (?), although you won't find it in the docs (which is stupid by the way).

I added it to my plunk, and it works now:

```
<form ngNoForm name="pdfForm" method="post" action="/goanywhere" 
    target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="mydata">
    <button type="submit">
      Download as Pdf
    </button
</form>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/0HULN4jvTicnmscK7D0o?p=preview

Comment: You're a life saver! I have a site with a bunch of PayPal buttons that just use a standard form submit, and they all broke when I added the reference to FormsModule for an unrelated area of the app. This simple fix saved the day!

Comment: Saved my day here, too!